# qgis-web-client stuck on Loading Map

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

I'm trying to publish a map created in qgis desktop via qgis-web-client.

The left hand bar loads with the layers I would expect visible but I never actually see any mapping data just a grey screen with "Loading Map....".

If I make the call to the qgis server manually via a web-browser e.g.

```
http://adddress/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/var/www/qgis-web-client/projects/test/filename.qgs&&_dc=1394809120649&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

I get what looks like valid XML returned.

In the chrome dev/javascript console I'm seeing error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'abstract' of undefined`

From webgisinit.js line 1680

`var thisAbstract = wmsLoader.projectSettings.service.abstract;`

Anyone seen this before or got any clues how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after initial installation. Just in case it can help someone else, my solution was to edit the project properties (Project > Project Properties), check "Service capabilities", in WMS check "CRS restrictions" and add EPSG:4326 (CRS I use for map layers) and check "Advertised extent" and set extent with "Use Current Canvas Extent". Note that for the latter I did set project CRS to EPSG:3857 to be able to have the project opened within the right extent.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by changing a little bit the code in WebgisInit.js, line 1781:

```
if (opacities) {
    for (layer in opacities) {
        if (opacities.hasOwnProperty(layer)) {
            try{
                wmsLoader.layerProperties[layer].opacity = opacities[layer];
            }catch(err){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is related with CRS. You have to set CRS as per your map. project >> project properties > CRS > select ((WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator  EPSG:3857 )) Apply >> ok