# Installing QGIS-Server on Ubuntu 14 (64-Bit AWS EC2 Instance), /cgi-bin/ doesn't work

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, qgis-server, apache

I've been trying to install qgis-server (2.14) on Ubuntu 14 (64-bit) using instructions from the the qgis-server [installation instructions](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial#QGIS-Server-configuration) and tips from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139569/install-qgis-server-and-web-client-under-ubuntu-14-04). All the packages install, I can access the Apache landing page and qgis-server is listed as an active service. However the api call below does not work. A call to the cgi-bin directory also doesn't work.

http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Does anyone know if there are extra steps needed outside the steps outlined in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the order of my installation was wrong. Running

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-fcgid
```

Before running

```
sudo apt-get install qgis-server
```

seemed to get QGIS-Server working. Alternatively, the [web-client git](https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client) actually has an install.sh file that seems to run the install commands needed to get QGIS-Server working with a front end. (I'm saying seems a lot because I haven't definitively tested these observations)